# Occupy a number from incrementation

Tags: javascript

what's the best method for occupying certain numbers from incrementation? For example I have a code that increments a value. I want to occupy all multipliers of 7 so the array is (1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,11,12,13,15..) so I can later on add my own values in the multipliers of 7.

```js
let x = 0;

let Array1 = [
  { user: 'mark', id: 1412, requeue: false },
  { user: 'john', id: 2612, requeue: false },
  { user: 'leo', id: 3743, requeue: false },
  { user: 'adam', id: 2414, requeue: false },
  { user: 'hasan', id: 51, requeue: false },
];

let Array3 = [];

// Add to all except multiples of 7
Array1.forEach((user) => {
  if (x % 7 === 0) {
    // Skip the number 7, 14, 21...
  } else {
    x++;
    // Else push the user to Array3
    // Array3.push({ ...singer, position: x });
  }
});

// Adding elements only on multiples of 7
let i = 0;
Array2.forEach((singer) => {
  i++;
  Array3.push({ ...singer, position: i * 7 });
});
```

Comment: You could try to divide the number by 7 and then do Number.IsInterger if that returns true its a multiplier of 7

Comment: How about making it as a Map with the number as key and then the number as value except numbers in the multipliers of 7 they could be undefined.

Then when using the map check if the value is undefined.

Comment: I would but I wanna use this array later so I could take away from it and the rest would update accordingly. A map just orders them for looks, I wanna utilize the array

Comment: What do you mean by "occupy"? It sounds like you actually want to skip these numbers.

Comment: Yeah, skip. Sure... Bad wording :)

Answer (score 0):

When `x` is a multiple of `7`, just do an extra increment.

```js
Array1.forEach((user) => {
  x++;
  if (x % 7 === 0) {
    x++;
  }
  Array3.push({...singer, position: x});
});
```